# Copying text from popup window

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

My employer uses SAP to generate purchase order numbers. The PO number is displayed in a popup window. I need to use VBA and SAP GUI Scripting to copy the PO number (or the whole text) so that it can be pasted into Excel.

I have tried using the SAP GUI script recording tool to get the command (it doesn't record the mouse clicks to select and copy, nor the keyboard commands), and it won't let me print to One Note or Microsoft XPS Document Writer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Image of the popup window is here:

[image]

Comment: Try [FindWindow API as shown in this SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098263/how-to-use-findwindow-to-find-a-visible-or-invisible-window-with-a-partial-name)

Answer (score 0):

The message is displayed in the status bar at the lower end of the screen.
with VBA you can read this as follows:

```
STATUS_BAR_TEXT = session.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer, for fellow programmers, to understand how exactly it helps to solve the problem?