# excel vba to Print a Document opened in IE browser

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I would like to Print a document which is downloaded from a webpage, document has been opened in a IE browser( inspect element option not present)using `send keys` i can print it, but if the file size is more while printing it shows as Printing is in progress. 
`Application.Wait`
will not help me to determine the wait time, please suggest is there is a any way to pause the execution of macro until printing progress is completed?

Function used to print:

```
Function Sample(tet As Variant)
Dim IE_Tab As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, ie As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML_Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim SH_Win As SHDocVw.ShellWindows, sh As Object
Dim T_Str As String
Set SH_Win = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

 For Each IE_Tab In SH_Win
     T_Str = IE_Tab.LocationURL
       If T_Str = tet Then
         Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
         Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
         'this command just populates the print dialog box, it worked fine only if i print an web page here iam trying to print a document opened as IE
         IE_Tab.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, 2, 0
         sh.AppActivate "Print"
         Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
         sh.SendKeys "c", 1
         Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        sh.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
         IE_Tab.Quit
            Exit For
     End If
Next
End Function
```

Print window:
[image: Print window]

Progress Window:

[image: Progress]

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried Doevents? [Application.DoEvents Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes i tried but its not getting the progress dialog box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a the help of some [Windows functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx), you can use a loop to "wait" until your *"Progress"* window is closed.

The API functions must be placed at the **top** of a module (or better yet, keep it tidy by putting this in it's own module.)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean

Sub WaitForWindowToClose(winCaption As String)
'pauses code execution until no window caption (title) matches [winCaption]

    Dim lhWndP As Long, sStr As String
    Dim foundWindow As Boolean, startTime As Single

    'loop through all windows
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
        'check if this window is a match
        If InStr(1, sStr, winCaption, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found Window: " & sStr & " (#" & lhWndP & ")"
            foundWindow = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, 2)
    Loop

    If Not foundWindow Then
        Debug.Print "Window '" & winCaption & "' not found."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check if window still exists
    Do While FindWindow(vbNullString, sStr) <> 0 And IsWindowVisible(lhWndP)
        'pause for a quarter second before checking again
        startTime = Timer
        Do While Timer < startTime + 0.25
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Window no longer exists."
End Sub
```

> ### Example Usage:
>
> **`WaitForWindowToClose "progress"`**
>
> ...pauses execution of code until there is no open window with *`progress`* in its' title bar.

The procedure looks for *case-insensitive, partial matches,* because window captions are not always what they appear to be.

This shouldn't be an issue unless you have another window open with a similar caption to the one you're waiting for.  For example, *`progress`* could refer to your printer's progress window, or a browser window called "Progressive Insurance".

---

### Troubleshooting:

The following procedures aren't necessary for operation of the above, but I figured I'd include them anyway, for troubleshooting purposes (ie., in case you're having trouble identifying your printer's progress window).

Usage should be self-explanatory:

```
Sub ListAllVisibleWindows()
    'Lists all named, visible windows in the Immediate Window
    Dim lhWndP As Long, sStr As String
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        x = x + 1
        sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        If Len(sStr) > 1 And IsWindowVisible(lhWndP) Then
            GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
            Debug.Print "#" & x, lhWndP, sStr
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, 2)
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function IsWindowOpen(winCaption As String) As Boolean
    'returns TRUE if winCaption is a partial match for an existing window
    Dim lhWndP As Long, sStr As String
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString)
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
        If InStr(1, sStr, winCaption, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found Window: " & sStr & " (#" & lhWndP & ")"
            IsWindowOpen = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, 2)
    Loop
End Function
```

<sub>(Code was adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098372/8112776).)</sub>

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad it worked.  There are a few ways those functions can come in handy when controls other applications from VBA.

Comment: The *Windows Functions* [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919(v=vs.85).aspx)? That's just a *handful* of the Windows API functions that can be called from VBA. ([Lots more info on Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=windows+api+functions+from+vba)). There's some pretty cool/handy things you can do. Some of them require some fairly "hardcore" coding but anything useful has examples online... but **use caution**: in used incorrectly, some of them can and will ₥Ɇ₴₴ ɎØɄⱤ ₴₮Ʉ₣₣ Ʉ₱!  ☺