# Suppress "Downloading File" box

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that references (with vba, no formulas) another workbook  that is stored remotely on a server.

I hope no problems opening the workbook, using my references and closing the workbook all without the user knowing apart from one major flaw. When I use `Workbooks.Open(MyPath)` it shows a "Downloading" box which reveals the location of this file. I do not want the users to see this.

[image: 1]

Is there a way to suppress this box?

I have tried `application.screenupdating = False`, `application.displayalerts = False`

Can't gather much from looking round the net, similar questions on forums go unanswered, but hours an hours of work hinges on this really as if the prompt can't be suppressed I need to scrap the whole thing.

Comment: If you need to open the remote workbook for reading only, and the data in that worbook isn't volatile, then you may just make a local copy of the file using FSO, and then open it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possibilities for you to consider and/or try.

The **fourth** option may be easiest/best:

1. You could get the window handle for the `Downloading` dialog using a Windows API, perhaps with the [GetWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515(v=vs.85).aspx) or [GetTopWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633514(v=vs.85).aspx) function ad then hide or otherwise manipulate the window as necessary. There are lots of samples online including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098263/how-to-use-findwindow-to-find-a-visible-or-invisible-window-with-a-partial-name) about using Windows API functions with Office.
2. It may be possible to programmatically map a drive letter (ie., `X:`) to the URL and open the file using the drive letter. More info [here](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=268572).
3. Maybe you can ***hotlink*** via a local file by creating a "dummy" page that basically just redirects to the file on the web.

   Here is an example using a random downloadable PDF cookbook online.  Copy the following into a Notepad and save it as `test.html`:

   ```
   <html>
   <body>
   <iframe 
     src="https://thestonesoup.com/blog/images/free_stonesoup_ecookbook.pdf" 
     frameborder="0" width="800" height="2500" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   Double-clicking the file will open it in your browser, and will automatically download (or prompt to download) the PDF, without giving any indication where the file is actually located.  This may or may not work with your case. More info [here](https://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/url-masking.php).
4. **The only true way to prevent a dialog produced by the `Workbooks.Open` method is to not use that method.**  Perhaps it would be best to download the file programmatically and then open the copy locally (which is what Excel's already doing for you anyhow).

   You could use a **[WinHTTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384263(v=vs.85).aspx)** File Download procedure like this:

   ```
    Sub downloadFile(fileURL As String, saveFilePath As String)
       Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream
       Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
       WinHttpReq.Open "GET", fileURL, False
       WinHttpReq.send
       If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
           Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
           oStream.Open
           oStream.Type = 1
           oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
           oStream.SaveToFile saveFilePath, 1 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
           oStream.Close
           Debug.Print "Saved: " & saveFilePath
       Else
           Debug.Print "Couldn't download: " & fileURL
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

**Example:**

This downloads the PDF to drive `c:\`:

```
    downloadFile "https://thestonesoup.com/blog/images/free_stonesoup_ecookbook.pdf", "c:\temp.pdf"
```

...the use **[Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/shell-function)** to open the file, something like:

```
    Shell ("excel.exe c:\yourFile.xlsx")
```

> ### An important note about securing information within Excel:
>
> ***You can't.***
>
> There is no guaranteed way of securing data or code within an Office document.  Even Excel's VBA Project password protection and encryption can be defeated fairly easily by even a novice user, using only Google and a little bit of determination (potentially in under 2 minutes).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, my remote file is on a server in our network so method 4 seems to fail. The path is like `\\ServerName\Folder\File.xlsm` rather than a HTTP address.

Comment: So you're not downloading the file per se, you're simply "opening it".