# How do I set focus on another open application?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button in My VBA excel code that when pushed it sets focus on another open windows application and inserts some text. I found some code that kinda works, but it doesn't switch to the other application, it opens a new one. how can I have it switch to the already open application?

Here is my code so far:

```
Public vPID As Variant
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    vPID = Shell("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus)
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "test" + "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

I am a beginner, and any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank You

Comment: `AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"`?

Comment: That did it! Thanks @GSerg

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in another thread: [How to use FindWindow to find a visible or invisible window with a partial name in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098263/how-to-use-findwindow-to-find-a-visible-or-invisible-window-with-a-partial-name)

I can't mark your question as a duplicate because the answer was never selected as correct by the one who asked.

I found the following code in [this vbforums.com answer](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?316924-Find-Window-handle-by-Partial-Caption) and *enhanced it to look for **visible or invisible** windows* as well, therefore hopefully answering both your questions:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "User32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function IsWindowVisible Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean

Private Const GW_HWNDNEXT = 2

Private Sub Test()

    Dim lhWndP As Long
    If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, "Excel") = True Then
        If IsWindowVisible(lhWndP) = True Then
          MsgBox "Found VISIBLE Window Handle: " & lhWndP, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        Else
          MsgBox "Found INVISIBLE Window Handle: " & lhWndP, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Window 'Excel' not found!", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

Private Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean

    Dim lhWndP As Long
    Dim sStr As String
    GetHandleFromPartialCaption = False
    lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
    Do While lhWndP <> 0
        sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
        GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
        sStr = Left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
        If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 Then
            GetHandleFromPartialCaption = True
            lWnd = lhWndP
            Exit Do
        End If
        lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop

End Function
```

The code searches for a window with a partial title of "Excel" and tells you if it found it and if it's a visible window or not. You should be able to adapt it for your own purposes.